# ProductID of Apple Bluetooth 2009 ANSI Keyboard

Tags: swift, bluetooth, keyboard, iokit

I am trying to get the battery levels of my connected bluetooth devices in Swift.
On my machine, all devices are detected properly.
However, the 2009 Apple Wireless Bluetooth ANSI keyboard connected via bluetooth is not detected (unfortunately I do not own this keyboard).

In my code I am using the following Bluetooth Product IDs:

```
WIRELESS_KEYBOARD_2009_ANSI = 0x0239
WIRELESS_KEYBOARD_2009_ISO = 0x023A
WIRELESS_KEYBOARD_2009_JIS = 0x023B
WIRELESS_KEYBOARD_2011_ANSI = 0x0255
WIRELESS_KEYBOARD_2011_ISO = 0x0256
WIRELESS_KEYBOARD_2011_JIS = 0x0257
MAGIC_KEYBOARD = 0x0267
WIRELESS_ANSI = 0x022C
WIRELESS_ISO = 0x022D
WIRELESS_JIS = 0x022E
```

I was pretty sure that it was 0x0239, but it looks like I was wrong. So does anyone use an Apple Bluetooth keyboard from 2009 and knows what the product ID for this device is?

I am using IOKit and searching in the "AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard" entry.

To find the keyboard, one could use the Explorer tool listed here: http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/IORegistryExplorer.shtml

Or use the terminal command: `ioreg -l | grep BatteryPercent`

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: I've got one of these. Have a quick way to tell?

Comment: The first command I'd suggest would be: ioreg -l | grep BatteryPercent    Another one would be using the IOReg Explorer. http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/IORegistryExplorer.shtml  Open the explorer and find the keyboard (search for Keyboard). I know this is a strange request, but without having this keyboard it is pretty hard to find the error...

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2009 Wireless Keyboard ([two batteries, dashboard button](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201806)). Here's the output from System Information:

```
Address:              00-25-BC-FB-2B-DB
Major Type:         Peripheral
Minor Type:         Keyboard
Services:             Apple Wireless Keyboard
Paired:             Yes
Configured:         Yes
Connected:          Yes
Manufacturer:         Apple (0x3, 0x31C)
Battery Level:      41%
Firmware Version:     0x0050
Vendor ID:          0x05AC
Product ID:         0x0239
Class of Device:      0x05 0x10 0x2540
AFH:                  On
AFH Map:              FFF7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F
RSSI:                 -62
Role:                 Master
Connection Mode:      Sniff Mode
Interval:             11.25 ms
Host Connectable:     Yes
EDR Supported:      No
eSCO Supported:     No
SSP Supported:      No
```

Looks like the product ID is 0x0239, like you thought.

---

Here's the relevant output of `ioreg -i` (no rows match the grep for BatteryPercent)

```
  +-o IOBluetoothHCIController  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBluetoothHCIController, id 0x10000035f, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (570 ms), retain 30>
  | +-o AppleBroadcomBluetoothHostController  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBluetoothHostController:BroadcomBluetoothHostController:AppleBroadcomBluetoothHostController, id 0x100000366, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (566 ms), retain 8>
  | | +-o IOBluetoothDevice  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBluetoothObject:IOBluetoothDevice, id 0x100000f27, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (45 ms), retain 12>
  | | | +-o IOBluetoothL2CAPSignalChannel  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBluetoothObject:IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel:IOBluetoothL2CAPSignalChannel, id 0x100000f28, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 8>
  | | | | +-o IOBluetoothL2CAPChannelUserClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUserClient:IOBluetoothL2CAPChannelUserClient, id 0x100000f29, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
  | | | +-o IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBluetoothObject:IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel, id 0x100000f2e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (44 ms), retain 8>
  | | | | +-o AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOHIDDevice:IOBluetoothHIDDriver:IOAppleBluetoothHIDDriver:AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard, id 0x100000f2f, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (8 ms), retain 9>
  | | | |   +-o IOHIDInterface  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOHIDInterface, id 0x100000f34, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (7 ms), retain 7>
  | | | |   | +-o AppleEmbeddedKeyboard  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOHIDEventService:IOHIDEventDriver:AppleEmbeddedKeyboard, id 0x100000f36, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 8>
  | | | |   |   +-o IOHIDEventServiceUserClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUserClient:IOHIDEventServiceUserClient, id 0x100000f3a, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
  | | | |   +-o IOHIDLibUserClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUserClient:IOHIDLibUserClient, id 0x100000f35, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
  | | | +-o IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBluetoothObject:IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel, id 0x100000f32, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
```

And of `ioreg -l`:

```
  | | | | +-o AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  <class AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard, id 0x100000f2f, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (8 ms), retain 9>
  | | | |   | {
  | | | |   |   "PrimaryUsagePage" = 1
  | | | |   |   "MaxInputReportSize" = 9
  | | | |   |   "IOUserClientClass" = "IOHIDLibUserClient"
  | | | |   |   "BatteryPanic" = No
  | | | |   |   "ReportDescriptor" = <05010906a1018501050719e029e71500250175019508810275089501810175019505050819012905910275039501910175089506150026ff00050719002aff008100c0050c0901a101854705010906a10205060920150026ff00750895018102c0c0050c0901a10185111500250175019503810175019501050c09b8810206ff0009038102750195038101050c8512150025017501950109cd810209b3810209b$
  | | | |   |   "VendorID" = 1452
  | | | |   |   "VersionNumber" = 80
  | | | |   |   "DeviceAddress" = "00-25-bc-fb-2b-db"
  | | | |   |   "SuspendSupported" = Yes
  | | | |   |   "HIDVirtualDevice" = No
  | | | |   |   "ExtendedFeatures" = {"FullFactoryDefault"={"id"=68,"type"=2},"RecantConnection"={"id"=65,"type"=2},"DeviceNameChange"={"id"=80,"type"=2},"DeviceName1"={"id"=81,"size"=8,"type"=2},"DeviceName2"={"id"=82,"size"=8,"type"=2},"DeviceName3"={"id"=83,"size"=8,"type"=2},"LongDeviceName"={"id"=85,"size"=64,"type"=2},"DeviceName4"={"id"=84,"size"=8,"$
  | | | |   |   "MaxFeatureReportSize" = 4
  | | | |   |   "Product" = "(my name)'s keyboard"
  | | | |   |   "SerialNumber" = "00-25-bc-fb-2b-db"
  | | | |   |   "PSM" = 17
  | | | |   |   "BatteryLow" = No
  | | | |   |   "Transport" = "Bluetooth"
  | | | |   |   "Elements" = ({"ReportID"=0,"ElementCookie"=1,"CollectionType"=1,"Type"=513,"Elements"=({"UnitExponent"=0,"IsRelative"=No,"UsagePage"=7,"Max"=1,"IsArray"=No,"Min"=0,"Type"=2,"Size"=1,"Flags"=2,"ReportID"=1,"Usage"=224,"ReportCount"=1,"Unit"=0,"HasNullState"=No,"IsNonLinear"=No,"HasPreferredState"=Yes,"ReportSize"=1,"ScaledMin"=0,"IsWrapping"$
  | | | |   |   "SetReportTimeoutMS" = 3500
  | | | |   |   "BatteryLowNotificationType" = "LowBattery"
  | | | |   |   "Manufacturer" = "Apple"
  | | | |   |   "ConnectionNotificationType" = "Connected"
  | | | |   |   "ProductID" = 569
  | | | |   |   "PoweredOffNotificationType" = "KeyboardOff"
  | | | |   |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=1,"CurrentPowerState"=1}
  | | | |   |   "BatteryDangerouslyLowNotificationType" = "CriticallyLowBattery"
  | | | |   |   "BD_ADDR" = <0025bcfb2bdb>
  | | | |   |   "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=1,"DeviceUsage"=6},{"DeviceUsagePage"=12,"DeviceUsage"=1})
  | | | |   |   "BatteryPercent" = 29
  | | | |   |   "ClassOfDevice" = 9536
  | | | |   |   "BTHIDObjectID" = 1378462720
  | | | |   |   "InputReportElements" = ({"ReportID"=1,"ElementCookie"=292,"Size"=72,"ReportCount"=1,"Type"=1,"UsagePage"=0,"ReportSize"=72,"Usage"=0},{"ReportID"=71,"ElementCookie"=293,"Size"=16,"ReportCount"=1,"Type"=1,"UsagePage"=0,"ReportSize"=16,"Usage"=0},{"ReportID"=17,"ElementCookie"=294,"Size"=16,"ReportCount"=1,"Type"=1,"UsagePage"=0,"ReportSize"=$
  | | | |   |   "ReportInterval" = 11250
  | | | |   |   "VendorIDSource" = 2
  | | | |   |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard"
  | | | |   |   "MaxOutputReportSize" = 2
  | | | |   |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"7DDEECA8-A7B4-11DA-8A0E-0014519758EF"="IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin","FA12FA38-6F1A-11D4-BA0C-0005028F18D5"="IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin"}
  | | | |   |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOBluetoothL2CAPChannel"
  | | | |   |   "LocationID" = 1023093723
  | | | |   |   "IOClass" = "AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard"
  | | | |   |   "DisconnectionNotificationType" = "Disconnected"
  | | | |   |   "PrimaryUsage" = 6
  | | | |   |   "HIDDefaultBehavior" = ""
  | | | |   |   "CountryCode" = 33
  | | | |   |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  | | | |   |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
  | | | |   |   "DeviceOpenedByEventSystem" = Yes
  | | | |   |   "IOProbeScore" = 2100
  | | | |   |   "GetReportTimeoutMS" = 3500
  | | | |   |   "DebuggingOn" = No
  | | | |   |   "BatteryState" = 0
  | | | |   | }
```

And ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | grep Battery`:

```
$ ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | grep Battery
  | | | |   |   "BatteryPanic" = No
  | | | |   |   "ExtendedFeatures" = {"FullFactoryDefault"={"id"=68,"type"=2},"RecantConnection"={"id"=65,"type"=2},"DeviceNameChange"={"id"=80,"type"=2},"DeviceName1"={"id"=81,"size"=8,"type"=2},"DeviceName2"={"id"=82,"size"=8,"type"=2},"DeviceName3"={"id"=83,"size"=8,"type"=2},"LongDeviceName"={"id"=85,"size"=64,"type"=2},"DeviceName4"={"id"=84,"size"=8,"type"=2},"BatteryState"={"size"=1,"id"=48,"min"=0,"max"=2,"type"=0},"BatteryPercent"={"size"=1,"id"=71,"min"=0,"max"=100,"type"=2},"WillShutdown"={"id"=64,"type"=2},"UserMode"={"size"=1,"id"=67,"min"=1,"max"=3,"type"=2},"FactoryDefault"={"id"=69,"type"=2}}
  | | | |   |   "BatteryLow" = No
  | | | |   |   "BatteryLowNotificationType" = "LowBattery"
  | | | |   |   "BatteryDangerouslyLowNotificationType" = "CriticallyLowBattery"
  | | | |   |   "BatteryPercent" = 29
  | | | |   |   "BatteryState" = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, so the ID is correct. Then I am most likely using the wrong IOKit command. Would you be so kind and try the command and the small tool?

Comment: @SaschaSimon Sure, send me a link.

Comment: I have added a comment previously and also edited my initial post.

Comment: That might be your issue, @SaschaSimon - no match for BatteryPercent in the lsreg output. See edit. I'm not able to install anything right now, but willing to help if you have more simple commands to run.

Comment: Can you open the Bluetooth menu on your Mac, select the connected keyboard and check if there is a battery indicator on the bottom left corner?

Comment: There is, @SaschaSimon.

Comment: Interestingly, there's also no output for BatteryPercent in the ioreg output for my Magic Keyboard on a different Mac.

Comment: That is really strange. I am searching for the key "AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard" this key is found. Can you run ioreg -n "AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard" or ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard

Comment: @SaschaSimon Running either of those appears to give the same output as normal `ioreg -i`, but running `ioreg -l` gives output including BatteryPercent, see edit. What version of OS X are you running? Feels like a difference in default output verbosity.

Comment: I am running the latest version, 10.12.4.

Comment: Almost the same here, 10.12.5. Interesting. What row matches for you in `ioreg -i | grep BatteryPercent`?

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot. You said from the beginning to use `ioreg -l`, I was using `-i`. I'm tired, should have caught that. So `-l` works as expected to find the correct item.

Comment: And ioreg, not lsreg. Could you try "ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | grep Battery" again?

Comment: ioreg, yes. Used to typing lsreg. Anyway, that command works. Output in answer.

Comment: I don't get it, i am 100% convinced that my code has to find the keyboard, I don't see any errors. But on a side noe, the ioreg command shows 29% battery level while the other command showed 41%. And what happens if you grep for battery again?

Comment: Been a while since it's been on. I suspect the battery calibration is way out of date.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Can I get in contact with you again soon? I will send you my app for further testing, I would really appreciate it ;)

Comment: I've got to run, let me know if you have anything else to run and I'll see what I can do in the morning. Also, if you're not on a super tight schedule, [those keyboards are super cheap](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=apple+2009+wireless+keyboard&_udlo=0&_udhi=30&_mPrRngCbx=1&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xa1314.TRS0&_nkw=a1314&_sacat=0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145562/discussion-between-sascha-simon-and-undo).